# mp3 Player for Windows and Android

Tags: windows, android, music, mp3

I'm looking for an mp3 player that will work for both Windows and Android.

I am keeping my music library (including playlists) in sync using [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite&hl=en_US&gl=US), and this works pretty well.

The problem is that I want to be able to edit playlists on Windows, and then (once a sync has happened) to be able to open the music app on android and to be able to find all my new/changed playlists.

I would even be open to a cloud-based player that would want to take over the sync aspect of this problem.

**What apps for Windows and Android for playing mp3 would satisfy these requirements?**

Comment: I use vlc player for everything, i.e., audio, video, streaming, etc.  It is free but accepts donations.  It can be a learning process to get on top of but afterwards I have found it capable of playing anything I am dealing with.  There are vlc apps for all devices., windows, android, linux, mac, etc  There is also purported to be a sync function, that I have never tried, to run playlists on different devices.

Comment: As you already sync a complete file structure it should also be possible to sync play list files as well. The only problem is that most players I know use absolute file path in playlists, which of course would not work for you. So a player that uses relative files paths (relative to the root directory you synchronize) in playlists should work.

Comment: "What apps are you using" is not considered a good question here. We don't do polls. Define your requirements and we'll see if there is such a software you need.

Comment: @ThomasWeller - updated the last line of the post, you are right

Comment: @Robert - I manually edit the playlists to use a relative path. But the problem is that when I sync a new playlist to the phone, the phone app that I currently use doesn't recognize that the playlist is there, and I need to add it manually. I would like to effectively sync the entirely library.